How to Query Bookmarked Posts Instead of Authored Posts in Sequelize
I’m new to Sequelize, so I apologize if my question seems basic. I have defined two models in my Sequelize setup: Post and User. I’m trying to query both the posts a user has authored and the posts they have bookmarked. However, I’m encountering an issue when querying the bookmarked posts.
Here are the relationships between my models:
//* for user and post : the creator is one-many each user could have multiple posts
User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId" });
Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" });

//* for user and post : the bookmark relation each user could book mark many posts each post could book mark by many users we ded
User.belongsToMany(Post, { through: "user_bookmark", as: "BookmarkedPosts" });
Post.belongsToMany(User, { through: "user_bookmark", as: "BookmarkedBy" });


When I query posts using the authenticated user (fetched from the database and passed via middleware), the query retrieves only the posts authored by the user instead of the ones they have bookmarked. Here's my current query:
// `req.user` is the authenticated user instance passed from middleware
let bookMarkedPosts = await req.user.getPosts({
  where: {
    is_active: true,
  },
  attributes: ["id", "image"],
  limit,
  page,
});

I believe this issue arises because getPosts refers to the posts authored by the user due to the hasMany relationship, not the ones bookmarked.
I have found solution but I have problem remaining, the junction table not being removed when using the ailias naming my query now is :
let posts=await user.getBookmarkedPosts({
      where:{
        is_active:true
      },
      attributes:['id','image','name'],
      through:{
// it's said that would remove junction table when empty array 
        attributes:[]
      }
     })

the result of this query  still has junction table :
{
            "id": "3a4454f5-70a8-45e5-bd32-1056709e1011",
            "image": "public\\upload\\post\\post.png",
            "name": "post",
            "User_Bookmarks": {
                "createdAt": "2024-11-20T07:02:18.869Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-11-20T07:02:18.869Z",
                "UserId": "e02719b6-a876-44c7-a535-ad380fccf5b3",
                "PostId": "3a4454f5-70a8-45e5-bd32-1056709e1011"
            }
        },


How can I correctly fetch the posts that the user has bookmarked? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

In case of named associations you should try to use get<association_name> method: getBookmarkedPosts in your case because getPosts indicates on your hasMany association with a default name Posts (a model name in plural form)

Thanks for your help. I have used it and worked but other problem occurred  the junction table included in each post even when I put attributes []

That's a thing for one more post. One post - one question!

I have found solution, also I appreciate  Anatoly's answer which helps me a lot. there 2 way we can achieve this query using that alias or using model it's self .
In alias way we could call the alias we assigned to user in m2m relation then add get before so in my case would be getBookmarkedPosts , in parentheses as like other queries we could user where or anything we want but unfortunately there is no ide or editor support for it we have to write it by our hands.
the code would be followed
let posts=await user.getBookmarkedPosts({
      where:{
        is_active:true
      },
      attributes:['id','image','name'],
      through:{
// it's said that would remove junction table when empty array 
        attributes:[]
      }
     })

But I have problem with this way! the junction table would not remove by adding the attributes:[] and maybe I have made mistake if you know please comment for me and other to learn it.
The other way which helped me a lot is using the model own self and alias. we would user User model then findAll and by providing where we would say only the user requested and then we would add include where we have to bring the post to play. in include we have to give our alias else would fetch written posts instead of bookmarked , and other parts are same you could use attributes in the include part to say only what you want from that model. The most important par is that we add through here and then empty array for attributes field to remove junction table per post returned .
the query would look like this
 let posts = await User.findAll({
        where: {
          id: req.user.id, // filtering for requesting user
        },
        attributes: [], // not including profile info 
        include: [
          {
            model: Post,
            through: {
              attributes: [],// removing junction
            },
            attributes: ["id", "image", "name"], // limiting needed attributes
            as: "BookmarkedPosts", // alias we assigned
            where: {
              is_active: true, // querying the active post
            },
          },
        ],
      });

I hope this help other
